# Height property reverts to previous value when changed

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to change the height value of a footer in my form, but when I try to change the height value and tab to the next property it reverts to the previous value that was there. I might have done something, as this is weird behavior that wasn't happening previously. Any way to solve this?

Comment: This is a design not programming issue and no code for analysis so question is not really appropriate for SO. Might want to post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide yours.

Comment: It is probably some hidden control in the footer.  I would make a new form and double check it is not an access issue by resizing the new forms footer.  Then I would open the properties sheet and examine all the form's controls in the combobox at the top of the properties sheet.  Look for an invisible control like an empty label.